# group values belonging to the same asset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset from which I want to create a pandas dataframe with the individual assets as column.

so `ETH-USD` would be the column name, followed by all the associated values that I have in my current dataframe.

It doesn't have to be a collective dataframe since the timestamps and number of available data for each asset vary. but that would certainly be a plus.

so the expected output would be

```
timestamp             ETH-USD 
2022-07-20 09:20:04 - 108.602000
2022-07-20 09:20:04 - 43.950700
```

...

What would be the easiest way to rearrange the dataframe that way?

```
                        asset  difference
timestamp                                
2022-07-20 09:17:32      NQ=F -245.344000
2022-07-20 09:20:04   ETH-USD -108.602000
2022-07-20 09:22:20      ^BFX    0.451244
2022-07-20 09:24:23     ^JKSE -240.189000
2022-07-20 09:26:22  ^BUK100P    3.504710
2022-07-20 09:37:50   ETH-USD   43.950700
2022-07-20 09:39:58      GC=F   81.669100
2022-07-20 09:41:48       SPY    1.634550
2022-07-20 09:43:34      YM=F  130.187000
2022-07-20 09:45:26      NQ=F -501.962000
2022-07-20 09:47:45      ^DJI -474.964000
2022-07-20 09:49:47     ^GSPC  -33.164600
2022-07-20 09:52:00     ^IXIC  -69.401100
2022-07-21 10:00:56   ETH-USD  -86.840600
2022-07-21 10:02:41      GC=F   26.784000
2022-07-21 10:04:26       SPY    2.501780
2022-07-21 10:06:11      YM=F -431.080000
2022-07-21 10:07:51      NQ=F -157.096000
2022-07-21 10:09:33      ^DJI  311.951000
2022-07-21 10:11:16     ^GSPC    6.179700
2022-07-21 10:12:58     ^IXIC -246.321000
2022-07-21 10:14:41      ^NYA  -19.314000
2022-07-21 10:16:25      ^XAX   44.954900
```

Comment: you mean, all the ETH-USD rows should come first ?

Comment: Can you please add the expected output

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for this:

```
# original DataFrame here stored as "df"

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='difference', index='timestamp', columns='asset')

print(df_pivot.head())

asset                ETH-USD  GC=F     NQ=F  SPY  ...  ^IXIC    ^JKSE  ^NYA  ^XAX
timestamp                                         ...                            
2022-07-20 09:17:32      NaN   NaN -245.344  NaN  ...    NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-07-20 09:20:04 -108.602   NaN      NaN  NaN  ...    NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-07-20 09:22:20      NaN   NaN      NaN  NaN  ...    NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-07-20 09:24:23      NaN   NaN      NaN  NaN  ...    NaN -240.189   NaN   NaN
2022-07-20 09:26:22      NaN   NaN      NaN  NaN  ...    NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Next, you can access the column `ETH-USD` as follows:

```
# pd.Series
df_pivot['ETH-USD'].dropna()

timestamp
2022-07-20 09:20:04   -108.6020
2022-07-20 09:37:50     43.9507
2022-07-21 10:00:56    -86.8406
Name: ETH-USD, dtype: float64

# or pd.DataFrame slice:
df_pivot[['ETH-USD']].dropna()

asset                 ETH-USD
timestamp                    
2022-07-20 09:20:04 -108.6020
2022-07-20 09:37:50   43.9507
2022-07-21 10:00:56  -86.8406
```

N.B. you asked for "all the associated values"; your expected output only gives the first *two* asocciated values for `ETH-USD`; I am assuming that this is a typo/oversight. Let me know if this assumption is erroneous.